# How to query using numeric id in Loopback

Tags: loopbackjs

I have a loopback model as

`{
      "name": "myModel",
      "base": "PersistedModel",
      "idInjection": true,
      "options": {
        "validateUpsert": true
      },
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "Channel name"
        }
      },
      "validations": [],
      "relations": {},
      "acls": [],
      "methods": {}
    }`

Now this is connected to a mongodb collection.This collection can have custom id in numeric like 1234 or Mongodb ObjectId when created using loopback.

Now when I query using GET 
    `http://localhost:3000/api/myModel/1234`.It is not able to get the object of that id.

I get an error message as 
    
     `{"status":404,"statusCode":404,"code":"MODEL_NOT_FOUND","message": "Unknown \"myModel\" id \"1234\"}`

If my id is alphanumeric like `abcd1234` then I dont get this error.Is there a way in loopback to be able to process a numeric id.
The only reference I have is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30634948/loopback-get-model-using-custom-string-id-from-mongodb) that suggests to use alphanumeric ids.